# Javascript count scope issue

Tags: scope, var

for some reason whenever I call overlayChange() when it checks the condition of count it sets count to 24, executes the code inside. I'm trying to identify when the count = 24 then set it back to 0.

overlayChange() is an onclick function to a clickable span element on the webpage.

```
    var count=0;
var name='HeatMap'.concat(count.toString());
var viewer = new Cesium.CesiumWidget('cesiumContainer');
var layers = viewer.scene.imageryLayers;

loadCesium();

function loadCesium()
{
    //Cesium Active Window
    layers.addImageryProvider(new Cesium.SingleTileImageryProvider({
        url : 'images/'.concat(name.concat('.png')),
        rectangle : Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0),
        opacity:.3
    }));
}
function overlayChange()
{
    if(count = 24)
    {
        count = 0;
        name='HeatMap';
        name = name.concat(count.toString());

        loadCesium();
    }
    else
    {
        name='HeatMap';
        count=count+1;
        name = name.concat(count.toString());

        loadCesium();
    }

}
```

Comment: if(count = 24) should be if(count == 24) or if(count === 24)

Comment: dude i just wanna cry now, I knew it was like that in Java but I thought javascript was different. Thanks

Comment: happens to the best of us